# SQL and Rails. Cannot open shared object file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR and SQL.

I installed MySQL and created a database for a project I am using with Rails. I was told to input Rails db:schema:dump after creating the database to see if it was working with rails and it gave me this error:

[See this error for the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOgr2.png)

I then decided to move on as I couldn't find a solution for the error above. However, when I tried to create a controller for rails it gave me the same error.

[Same error trying to create a controller for rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPf2d.png)

Hope someone could help/give me a guiding hand!

Thanks

Comment: What OS do you use? What is the response to `gem install mysql2`?

Comment: It gave me an error, however it advised me to input this command. 'sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev'. After, gem install mysql2 worked and all my above errors are fixed! Thank you spickermann. (I use Ubuntu 16.04). Do you know why it is working now?

Comment: development libraries and header files apparently :/